# Storing html form to my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am newbie and I am working on project that Needed simple three things.

1. Create a html form
2. to take inputs from user
3. save the form to database and view by admin.

This form will be running locally.

Based on the internet search and also reading from this community I have wrote code  for registration.html, connection.php,modified.php,listing.php and using xampp tool In phpmyadmin I have created table for each entry.

Here when I insert the data in form and save,Its not saving in database.

this is my table entries I have created using phpmyadmin [phpmyadmin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLHJM.jpg)

my registration page code

`

```
  <html>    
        <head>    
            <title>Registration Form</title>    
        </head>    
        <body>    
            <link href = "registration.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />    
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>    
            <form name = "form1" action="modified.php" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >    
                <div class = "container">    
                    <div class = "form_group">    
                        <label>First Name:</label>    
                        <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "" required/>    
                    </div>    
                    <div class = "form_group">    
                        <label>Middle Name:</label>    
                        <input type = "text" name = "mname" value = "" required />    
                    </div>    
                    <div class = "form_group">    
                        <label>Last Name:</label>    
                        <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "" required/>    
                    </div>    
                    <div class = "form_group">    
                        <label>Password:</label>    
                        <input type = "password" name = "pwd" value = "" required/>    
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form_group">
                        <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                        <input type = "confirm password" name = "cnf" value = "" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form_group">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type = "Email Address" name = "mail" value = "" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form_group">
                        <label>Contact No:</label>
                        <input type = "contact number" name = "number" value = "" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form_group">
                        <label>Gender:</label>
                        <input type = "gender" name = "sex" value = "" required/>
                    <button class="button" id="join"></button>
                </div>    
            </form>    
        </body>    
    </html>
```

`
my connection.php file where I wrote connection properties.

`

```
 <?php  
           $servername = "localhost";  
           $username = "root";  
           $password = "";  
           $dbname = "registration"
           $conn = mysql_connect ($servername , $username , $password, $dbname) or die("unable to connect to host");  
           $sql = mysql_select_db ('test',$conn) or die("unable to connect to database"); 
    ?>
```

`
Here is My listing.php file

`

```
<?php    

include "connection.php";    

if(isset($_GET['id'])){    
$sql = "delete from registration where id = '".$_GET['id']."'";    
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
}    

$sql = "select * from registration";    
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
?>    
<html>    
    <body>    
        <table width = "100%" border = "1" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "1">    
            <tr>    
                <td>Id</td>    
                <td>First Name</td>    
                <td>Middle Name</td>    
                <td>Last Name</td>    
                <td>Password</td>    
                <td>Confirm Password</td>    
                <td>Email</td>    
                <td>Contact No.</td>    
                <td>Gender</td>    
                <td colspan = "2">Action</td>    
            </tr>    
        </table>    
    </body>    
</html>    
<?php    

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){    


?>  
    <tr>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->id;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->fname;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->mname;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->lname;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->pwd;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->cnf;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->mail;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->number;?>  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $row->sex;?>  
        </td>  
        <td> <a href="listing.php?id =     
            <?php echo $row->id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure')">Delete    
        </a> | <a href="index.php?id =     
            <?php echo $row->id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure')">Edit    
        </a> </td>  
        <tr>  
            <? php } ?>
```

`

Comment: (1) don't see an `INSERT` code block, so if your issue is saving to a database it might be helpful if you actual include that code. (2) time to update all your `mysql_` code to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: @Sean. Thank you for the reply. can you tell me where and how I put `INSERT`. And Yes, Once this is working I will update to mysqli as advised.

Comment: If you have issue with saving, then it will be helpful if you include saving code.

Comment: @AbyPaul:- I have prob with saving only and If you can show me how do I insert saving code or point me to example will be good for me,

Comment: for examples you can refer w3schools.. why r u wasting ur time here... if u wanna know what's wrong with ur code u must include ur code here.. then only someone can help u.. dats wot i have experienced from here.

Comment: @AbyPaul :-  Its not clear to me what do I write in saving code or Insert code. My understanding was creating connection.php will do connect html page to phpmyadmin. but its not happening. all codes which I have are posted here.